# Pregunta sobre la función mysqli_num_rows de PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un sistema de comentario y para evitar que se repita el mismo comentario uso la función mysqli_num_rows, pero me da este error

> warning   mysqli_num-rows () expeter parameter 1 to be  mysqli_result
>   boolean given

Y me repite el registro ingresado,este es mi código

```
public function insertarComentario(){

        if(empty($_POST["nombre"]) or empty($_POST["correo"]) or empty($_POST["comentarios"]) or empty($_POST["id"])){

            header("Location: ".$_POST["url"]);


              }else{

            $sql="select id_comentario from comentario where
            nombre=nombre
            and 
            correo=correo
            and
            comentario=comentario
            id_noticia=id ";
            $datos=$this->db->query($sql);


            if(mysqli_num_rows($datos)==0){ 



           //header("Location: ".$_POST["url"]);
 $sql="INSERT  INTO comentario VALUES
(null,'".$_POST["nombre"]."','".$_POST["correo"]."','".$_POST["comentarios"]."',now(),now(),'".$_POST["id"]."','".$_POST["estado"]."');
   ";

            //mysqli_query($datos);
         $this->db->query($sql);
           //mysqli_query($sql);

            echo "<script>
            alert('Gracias por escribir el comentario.sera mostrado cuando sea moderado');
            window.location='".$_POST["url"]."';
            </script>";  
          }else{  

            header("Location: ".$_POST["url"]); 

}
}
}
}
```

muchas gracias de antemano saludos.

Comment: En la consulta que haces antes de comprobar el número de registros, parece que no estás poniendo los valores de los cambios, sino que haces referencia a los mismos campos excepto id_noticia que apunta a id. Creo que no tiene sentido y que deberías poner los valores que te llegan en el POST

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error que te regresa es bastante descriptivo, `mysqli_num_rows` espera como parámetro un objeto `mysqli_result` y tú le estás pasando un booleano.

La documentación de mysqli query nos dice

> Retorna FALSE en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, mysqli_query() retornará un objeto mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de mysqli_query() retornará TRUE.

Esto nos da a entender que si tu consulta está mal hecha retornará `FALSE` (Un booleano).

Revisando tu consulta notamos que

```
 $sql="select id_comentario from comentario where
        nombre=nombre
        and 
        correo=correo
        and
        comentario=comentario
        id_noticia=id ";
```

La consulta está mal, dado que si nombre es char, va entre comillas simples

```
$sql="select id_comentario from comentario where
        nombre= 'nombre'
        and 
        correo= 'correo'
        and
        comentario= 'comentario'
        id_noticia=id  //si este es numero va como número y sin comillas simples"
```

Ahora por lo que se aprecia lo que realmente tratas de hacer es pasar los parametros POST a la consulta, por lo que debió quedar así

```
$sql="select id_comentario from comentario where
        nombre='".$_POST['nombre']."'
        and 
        correo='".$_POST['correo']."'
        and
        comentario='".$_POST['comentario']."'
        id_noticia=".$_POST['id']
```

NOTA la forma de realizar esto no es la recomendada debido al sql injection, la mejor manera es con `consultas preparadas`, te recomiendo buscar información acerca de eso para hacerlo de la manera correcta.

Comment: `and`  falta un `and`  en el último criterio: `and comentario= 'comentario' AND id_noticia=id`. Otra cosa, es muy cierto lo que adviertes sobre la inseguridad de su código al no usar consultas preparadas, pero debe tenerse en cuenta cuando se vaya a usar `num_rows` en consultas preparadas es necesario llamar antes a `store_result`, de  lo contrario no funcionará.

Comment: ok.gracias ,bueno lo que pasa es que me estoy iniciando en la programacion y lo estoy haciendo de esta forma poque voy poco a poco, y si tienes toda la razon con lo de la seguridad en las consultas ya habia le habia dado un vistazo a las consultas preparadas.No me queda mas que agradecerte por compartir tu conocimiento me sacaste de varias dudas en cuanto a las consultas y muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder,saludos y bendiciones hermano.